# Missing database entries with a null value in row, when performing a linq statment

Tags: sql, database, linq, null, missing-data

so here's the sql query:

```
Select distinct A.CategoryName, A.CategoryID, B.ProjectID 
from [EvalTool].[dbo].[Category] A
Left Join [EvalTool].[dbo].[CategoryAndProject2] B
On A.CategoryID = B.CategoryID AND B.ProjectID = 65
```

and the hopefully equal linq statement:

```
int pID = (int)Session["projectSession"];
             ViewData.Model = (from c in _db.Category
                                join r in _db.CategoryAndProject2
                                on c.CategoryID equals r.CategoryID into join1
                                from j in join1.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                where j.ProjectID == pID
                                select new CategoryDTO
                                {
                                    CatID = c.CategoryID, 
                                    CatName = c.CategoryName,
                                    ProjID = (int) j.ProjectID
                                }).Distinct().ToList();
```

the result for the sql statement is the following table:

```
CategoryName    ID  ProjectID
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
x   1   NULL
y   2   NULL
z   3   NULL
m   4   NULL
n   5   NULL
i   6   NULL
o   7   NULL
r   8   NULL
s   9   65
u   10  65
```

whereas the linq statement only lists 2 rows, those without a null entry.

```
CategoryName    ID  ProjectID
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
s   9   65
u   10  65
```

but I need those rows with a null entry in my view.

How can I make sure to also select those?

thanks a lot in advance
mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The offending line,

```
where j.ProjectID == pID
```

is filtering on `ProjectID`, and logically will not return null rows unless `pID` is itself null. In your case it would appear to be `65` and thus the line should be changed to

```
where j.ProjectID == pID || j.ProjectID == null
```

Alternatively, if you want to put it in the `ON` part of the join, you can do:

```
from c in _db.Category
join r in _db.CategoryAndProject2
   on new {c.CategoryID, ProjectID = pID} equals new {r.CategoryID, r.ProjectID} 
   into join1
```

---

Following this, the assignment

```
ProjID = (int) j.ProjectID
```

in your `select` statement will fail. You will have to decide what to do with it.

Comment: many thanks. now I just need to find a way how to handle j.Project as nullable.

Comment: @marko_tek Sure. The simplest would probably be to modify `CategoryDTO.ProjID` to be an `int?`, if that is acceptable for your business logic

Comment: declaring ProjID as int? works fine, but the struggle continues. Now I receive different results, when I additionaly use the orderby-statement. depending on whether ordering by CategoryName or CategoryID the results consists of 6 or 7 entries. How is this possible? 

It's not only the count that is different, I also see different rows

Comment: @marko_tek I'm not sure without seeing the exact results you're getting and the queries you are doing. I suggest you open a new question and explain your new problem, possibly linking back to this question if you wish.

Comment: as I found out the reason for different results is, that I am filtering by using your where-statement. I guess I need to first filter on the ON-part of the linq-statement. but your suggestion doesn't work. 

"The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect. Type inference failed in the call to 'GroupJoin'."

Comment: Is `pID` nullable and `r.ProjectID` not (or vice versa)? In which case I believe you need a cast to make both sides the same type.

Comment: as I found out, c.CategoryID is int and r.CategoryID is int?
but the following cast doesn't work:
`join r in _db.CategoryAndProject2
 on new { c.CategoryID, ProjectID = pID } equals new { Cat2 = (int) r.CategoryID,  r.ProjectID } 
 into join1`

Comment: I think you'll have to go the other way (`(int?)c.CategoryID`) otherwise you'll get exceptions if `r.CategoryID` is null?

Comment: Hang on, it looks like you have a `Cat2 = ...` on the right hand side? The names of each property on both sides have to be the same.

Comment: `on new { c.CategoryID, ProjectID = (int?)pID } equals new { r.CategoryID, ProjectID = (int?) r.ProjectID }`
doen't work neither